# OpenSSL produces core dump under Valgrind due to RDRAND

Tags: c, openssl, valgrind

This is my code:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int main(){
    BIGNUM *bne = NULL; 
    unsigned long e = RSA_F4;
    RSA *r = NULL;

    bne = BN_new();
    BN_set_word(bne,e);
    r = RSA_new();
    int ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, 1024, bne, NULL);

    const BIGNUM *n = NULL;
    const BIGNUM *d = NULL;
    RSA_get0_key(r, &n, NULL, &d);

    BN_print_fp(stdout, n);
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);

    return  0;
}
```

This is how I compiled it:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wl,-rpath,/home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib -g sharedLibraryTest.c -o sharedLibraryTest -I/home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/include - L/home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib -lcrypto -ldl
```

Everything is ok, when I run it normally with `./sharedLibraryTest`. However, when I run it in Valgrind, it says `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` and there are some memory leaks I don't understand (I can't see any).

Do you know what causes this? I am running OpenSSL 1_1_0e.

---

Here is the Valgrind output.

```
$ valgrind ./sharedLibraryTest 
==4500== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4500== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4500== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4500== Command: ./sharedLibraryTest
==4500== 
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x48 0xF 0xC7 0xF0 0x72 0x2 0xE2 0xF8
vex amd64->IR:   REX=1 REX.W=1 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=0F
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
==4500== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x5026fa5.
==4500==    at 0x5026FA5: OPENSSL_ia32_rdrand (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4FC2B12: rand_bytes (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4EF698E: BN_rand (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4EF5430: BN_generate_prime_ex (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4FCA616: RSA_generate_key_ex (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x400963: main (sharedLibraryTest.c:12)
==4500== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==4500== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==4500== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==4500==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==4500==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==4500== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==4500==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==4500==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==4500== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==4500== probably kill your program.
==4500== 
==4500== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==4500==  Illegal opcode at address 0x5026FA5
==4500==    at 0x5026FA5: OPENSSL_ia32_rdrand (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4FC2B12: rand_bytes (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4EF698E: BN_rand (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4EF5430: BN_generate_prime_ex (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x4FCA616: RSA_generate_key_ex (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==4500==    by 0x400963: main (sharedLibraryTest.c:12)
==4500== 
==4500== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4500==     in use at exit: 6,216 bytes in 32 blocks
==4500==   total heap usage: 146 allocs, 114 frees, 14,880 bytes allocated
==4500== 
==4500== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4500==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4500==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4500==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4500==    still reachable: 6,216 bytes in 32 blocks
==4500==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4500== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4500== 
==4500== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4500== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Comment: Where did your copy of OpenSSL 1.1.0 come from? Is it standard or "official" from the OpenSSL project; or does it have patches applied to it from a vendor?

Comment: I can tell you exactly - from here:  https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/OpenSSL_1_1_0e.tar.gz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a known bug in valgrind, for which there is already a [patch](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353370#c9).

The problem is that valgrind does not support the CPU instruction that libcrypto is using. The solution is to not tell libcrypto that this instruction is available.

The memory leaks is most likely the result of an abnormal termination. That is, the destructors of different objects are not called.

**Solutions**

1. Get the latest stable version
2. Apply the patch
3. Get the SVN version from the online repo